# Custom SMTP is updating the Links in email body EXM

Tags: exm

we are using netcore smtp service for EXM, when i add any link in message body and send the email,
the link in the body is changed to some different, the link appends netcore domain at the begining of the url.
How can i fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the "Base URL" field in email manager ?

Comment: I am adding an external link how will the base url help in this. The said url contains trk.netcore.com and then some value. it is maybe for tracking purpose, but not sure why is it adding the same.

Comment: Every link in EXM will replace with default pattern (get domain name from the base url). you can add custom link through CustomTokens.

Comment: it is not the base url, base url is added. the link is replaced by some trk.netcore.com and then some id.

Comment: It’s is used by Netcore to track the clicks from the email. It will still take you to the url which you defined in the mail body. I’m sure netcore should be able to disable this url update in email body